# Harvard reference list for citing disjoint passages from the same text

Tags: citations

I'm writing something in which I want to cite page 50 of *Mathematical Thought from Ancient to Modern Times* at one point, and page 83 of the same text at another point. This is no problem for in-text citations, since I say "(Kline, M. 1972, p. 50)" when I want to cite page 50, and "(Kline, M. 1972, p. 83)" when I want to cite page 83. However, it presents an issue in the reference list, since I want to indicate the pages I have used from each text in the reference list. I could write

"Kline, M. (1972). *Mathematical Thought from Ancient to Modern Times*. New York: Oxford University Press, pp. 50 - 83.",

but that would imply that I have used every page from page 50 to page 83, which is not true and I do not want to be implied. I could also create two references for the same text, one citing page 50 and other page 83, but I don't know if this is the proper thing to do. I want to be able to write something like

"Kline, M. (1972). *Mathematical Thought from Ancient to Modern Times*. New York: Oxford University Press, p. 50, p.83.",

but again I don't know if this is the proper thing to do. How do I cite disjoint passages from the same text without implying that I have used everything between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I cite disjoint passages from the same text without implying that I have used everything between them?

In the reference list, write:

```
Kline, M. (1972). Mathematical Thought from Ancient to Modern Times. New York: 
Oxford University Press.
```

I.e., omit page numbers. In the main body, write *(Kline, M. 1972, p. 50)* and *(Kline, M. 1972, p. 83)*, as you already have. In some disciplines, you can also write *(Kline, M. 1972, p. 50)* followed by *(ibid, p. 50)*, when no other citations appear inbetween.

Comment: Would leaving the pages numbers out of the reference list be seen as lazy? Most reference lists I see have the page numbers included, and this work is going to be marked so I don't want something like that acting as a disadvantage.

Comment: @windingnumberone _Most reference lists I see have the page numbers included_, when page numbers are included, are they included for books? Or manuscripts (e.g., journal articles, conference papers, book chapters, ...) which form part of a larger collection? For the latter, page numbers should be included in the reference list (for a book chapter, the chapter number can be included, rather than page numbers). For the former, I have never seen page numbers in the reference list, I have seen them in the main body. (You can also include page numbers in the many body for other works.)

Comment: That's a good point. They aren't used for books. Thanks.